# Asp.net C# equivalent to this curl Post request

Tags: c#, asp.net

$ curl

-X POST

-H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

-F 'recipients[0][fullname]=John' -F 'recipients[0][email]=john.doe@gmail.com'

-F 'files[0]=@NDA.pdf'

-F 'delivery_type=url'

https://api.sandbox.signaturit.com/v3/signatures.json

I have done this "translation to asp.net" I am new in this job and i am learning ASP.NET MVC C#.

```
 public static string SendSignatureRequest(string apiKey, string name, string email, string file)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.signaturit.com/v3/signatures.json");
    request.Method = "POST";

    var postData = "&signers[0][name]=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name);
        postData += "&signers[0][email_address]=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email);
        postData += "&file_url[0]=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file);// OR -- postData += "&file[0]=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file);


    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    string authorization = apiKey;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authorization);

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

But i kept getting 401 error!